# How one explains why rigid body part some point moves in a different way even though from outside its looks force will move it their way?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Suppose a simple example where a body like in figure on a frictionless plane is given an impulsive force on one end  , i know by rotation way -we can treat it as motion around COM, but i want to know what causes motion of any part of the body which is moving in different direction to force appllied  (like downward etc) for example in the figure example where one can see rod end B is going towards down but force is applied horizontal towards right , i want to know what happens inside so that there is a downward motion of the below rod end. [image]

Comment: Is a diagram needed?

Comment: What do you mean by "moving in the opposite direction"?
If you have a rigid rod lying on the frictionless surface and you push homogeneously from one side (i.e. the force is applied equally on every point of the surface) the rod will slide forward, but nothing will move opposite to the applied force

Comment: Different situation if the rode is lying vertically, and if you push the bottom of the rod it will be unbalanced, but that just a rotation issue...

Comment: Oh wait now i see , figure is needed , wait

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "other end tends to move in opposite direction of where the force is applied"

Comment: The end B moves in which direction (its a bit left going and then coming to right during the whole motion ) refer to the image Sir

Comment: From the figure, the rod is fixed in the center. 
Perhaps I start to understand your doubt...Your system has a constrain, that is the fixed point. When you push, that constrain (un-removable) will counteract your force by applying an equal force in the opposite direction.
Imagine yourself pushing a wall. The wall will not move, because it is applying an identical force in the opposite direction.

Comment: Your image is too large to work on the built-in Imgur image hosting.  Try uploading a lower-resolution version.

Comment: I mean what causes that part of rod to move left , as such there is no force which is left ward going below the midpoint of rod and  upwards too during the whole motion

Comment: Image uploaded Sir

Comment: @gbon consider this situation it would be more better than this example : suppose the example in the second figure now the rod part at end B tends to move down even though force applied is horizontal , may you now see what my doubt is , i am not able to figure out how end B tends to move where force is not even applied :

Comment: Second figure? I only see one, where you push the A-side

Comment: Yeah wait Sir , reducing quality is very tough :(

Comment: Done Sir , may you please now delete your close option bc i give the best example possible :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to show that with any system of particles the vector sum of the external forces determines the acceleration of the center of mass. In your example, if the top of the rod exceeds the acceleration of the center of mass, then the forces which accelerate the bottom of the rod backward must the the inter-atomic forces within the rigid rod. The impulse at the top also provides a torque which causes the rod to rotate (as a rigid body) about its center.

Comment: Is it possible to show by a cut out portion of rod a fbd of the lower end and how it gets a force downward Sir ?

Answer (score 0):

To conserve angular momentum. Both angular and linear momentum must be conserved in rigid body motion. If any force $F$ is applied at any distance $r$ from the center of mass, it will cause a moment

$M=r×F$

about that center of mass. That moment must either cause an angular acceleration (rotation that you are seeing) or be balanced by an opposing moment.  If you take the cross product of both sides of Newton's second law, you can see this:

$r×\Sigma F=r×(ma)$

$\Sigma M=I\alpha$

($I=$ moment of inertia, $\alpha=$ angular acceleration)

That is why for 2D rigid body mechanics, both the equations below must be satisfied:

$\Sigma F=ma$

$\Sigma M=I\alpha$

The center of mass will obey the first equation, so the center of the rod *will* move to the right in your example.  And the rest of the points on the rod will rotate according to the second equation.

[I don't really know how to do vector arrows well in Latex, but hopefully it's clear enough]